# python script for creating maproxy OGC WMS service using Mapnik and PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, mapnik

Would that be possible to create programatically a new OGC WMS (1.1/1/3) service using:

1. Python
2. MapProxy
3. Mapnik
4. PostGIS/Postgres

any script/gist or sample would be more then appreciated.

Cheers, M

Answer (score 0):

In general everything is about configuration files. I create automatically new WMS endpoints for my Mapserver/Mapproxy setup with a python script, which also process my images.

MapServer config-pattern:

```
MAP
  NAME "WMS Server"
  #IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
  IMAGETYPE custom
  TRANSPARENT OFF
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" [error.txt]
  EXTENT [Extent]
  SIZE 800 600
  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_title"           [title]
      "wms_srs"             [epsg]
      "wms_enable_request"  "*"
    END
  END
  PROJECTION
    "init=[epsg]"
  END

  INCLUDE [layer list]

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "custom"
    DRIVER "GDAL/GTiff"
    MIMETYPE "image/tiff"
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    TRANSPARENT ON
    EXTENSION "tif"
    FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=1.0"
  END
END
```

Mapproxy config-pattern:

```
caches:
  [cache folder]:
    cache:
      directory_layout: tms
      type: file
    grids:
    - webmercator
    image:
      format: image/png
      mode: RGBA
      resampling_method: bilinear
      encoding_options:
        jpeg_quality: 100
      transparent: true
    meta_size:
    - 2
    - 2
    sources:
    - [source]
globals:
  cache:
    base_dir: [base dir]
    lock_dir: [lock dir]
    tile_lock_dir: [tile lock dir]
  image:
    paletted: false
grids:
  webmercator:
    base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    num_levels: 22
layers:
- name: [layer name]
  sources:
  - [cache]
  title: [title]
services:
  demo: null
  wms:
    md:
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
    srs:
    - [epsg]
sources:
  45_source:
    coverage:
      datasource: [coverage datasource]
      srs: [epsg]
    mapserver:
      binary: [mapserver binary]
      working_dir: /
    req:
      layers: [mapserver layer name]
      map: [mapserver mapfile]
      transparent: true
    supported_formats:
    - image/tiff
    supported_srs:
    - [epsg]
    type: mapserver
```

Everything you have to do is to split up the config into different parts, which you then can edit with a python script.

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking for publish data in postgres to WMS, enable tilecache, and use more advanced rendering engine like mapnik, then I would say there could be one component missing is the GIS server.

So if I am guessing your requirement correctly as I mentioned earlier then here is what the system design could be:

1. Use postgres/postgis as database connection.
2. Write your own server side program using python to create the
   service definition file for the dynamic WMS (mapfile if you are
   going to use MapServer).
3. Then your program handling tilecache/tile seeding by change the
   configuration file (.yaml) in mapproxy.
4. Then escalate WMS to mapnik for rendering and expose the output.
   Like someone else mentioned, it would be easy to have a template
   configuration file for each step and do parameter substitution.